# Is it possible to call/await an async function without all the parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I'm trying to post a `'x-www-form-urlencoded'` data into the Twitter API. There's four parameters that can be filled, `sender_screen_name`, `status`, `attachment_url`, and `media_ids`.

Example code:

```
async function postTweet(sender_screen_name, status, attachment_url, media_ids) {

const sendTwt = {
    url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json',
    oauth: oAuthConfig,
    form: {
    status: status,
    attachment_url: attachment_url,
    media_ids: media_ids
    }
};
console.log(`[${time}] [CONSOLE] Tweeted user @${sender_screen_name}'s message`);
await post(sendTwt);
}
```

Now here's the catch, if I call it like this:

```
await postTweet(senderScreenName, encodeMsg);
```

It is succesfully posted, with just only filling in the `sender_screen name` and `status` parameter. Now, on another call, I wanted to fill the fourth parameter (`media_ids`) and left the third one (`attachment_url`) blank or without anything in it.

I tried to call it with a `null` like this:

```
await postTweet(senderScreenName, encodeMsg, null, encodeImg);
```

But, now it returns a 400 Bad Request error. In what ways can I proceed with this?

Comment: `await postTweet(senderScreenName, encodeMsg, undefined, encodeImg);`

Comment: Passing arguments in a call works the the same for all functions, it doesn't matter whether it's `async` or not, and certainly it does not matter whether you `await` the promise that the call returns or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await postTweet(senderScreenName, encodeMsg);` is equivalent to `await postTweet(senderScreenName, encodeMsg, undefined, undefined);`.

So, try `await postTweet(senderScreenName, encodeMsg, undefined, encodeImg);`